# how to connect to FoxPro db in SSIS 2008

Tags: ssis, foxpro, visual-foxpro

Recently I got a FoxPro DB which is using in an SSIS package connected by OLE DB Source. So, if I open OLE DB Source and click on Columns it gives the bellow message

[image]

Well do not have FoxPro installed. So, what do I have to do to get data from the FoxPro DB source.

Answer (score 0):

Just [download](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14839) and install VFPOLEDB provider, then try again.